# Apache Camel web service with support for XML and JSON

Tags: apache-camel

I am developing REST service. Can I use Apache CAMEL to support XML and JSON format? I don't have much knowledge about how to use Apache CAMEL. If someone know any example, can you point me there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [Camel HTTP Endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) with Camel's [JSON support](http://camel.apache.org/json.html). The code and configuration samples in both resources should get you on your way.

Bear in mind you have other options like [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy), [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), and [Restlet](http://restlet.org/) for pure REST services with JSON. Camel (and [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), etc) support messaging via the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/). REST may be a part of that of course, but make sure you only do as much as you have to to support your needs.

Comment: I couldn't understand well with the example provided. Can you point me somewhere where they use CAMEL to support different data formats

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://jaxenter.com/tutorial-integrating-with-apache-camel-48211.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [cxf bean component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html) will attempt to marshal the response to whatever was requested by the client. A simple "REST route" could look like this:

```
<camel:from ref="jettyEndpoint" />
<camel:to uri="cxfbean:yourRequestHandler?providers=#jsonJacksonProvider..." />
```

In the bean referenced as "yourRequestHandler" you can use standard JAX-WS annotations on your service methods. E.g.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public ServiceResponse aServiceMethod(ServiceResponse response) {
    // Do whatever is required to gather the information for the response here...
    // Then create response object, will be marshaled according to annotation
    ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();
    return response;
}
```

I am not sure if you need to provide separate service methods to produce JSON and XML or if you can do it in one and. We always only produce one format and in that case the cxfbean will automagically marshal to the annotated format. You might have to supply it with the needed providers though. E.g. if you are not happy with the standard JSON provider and rather want to use Jackson, then you can override the default provider by providing your own like in the cxfbean URI above.

Beware, if you add route steps after the cxfbean step, then the exchange body will contain your response object already marshaled in the client requested format.